# PHP/SQL: Why does the loop with mysqli_fetch_assoc not work?

Tags: php, mysql

I fetch some data from a sql db and want to loop trough every row.

This is what i wrote:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bewertungen;");

while($rating = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    echo "number of rows: " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . "<br>";
    $sql="
        SELECT SUM(rating_direction)
        FROM commentratings
        WHERE comment_ID = '".$rating['ID']."';
    ";
    echo "ratingID: " . $rating['ID'] . "<br>";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if (FALSE === $result) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $sum = $row[0];
    if ($row[0] == false) $sum = 0;

    echo "sum: " . $sum ."<br>";

    $sql="
        UPDATE bewertungen
        SET Bewertung_Kommentar = '$sum'
        WHERE ID = ".$rating['ID'].";
    ";

    if ($con->query($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo 'success';
    }
}

?>
```

When I run it, it returns

```
number of rows: 6
ratingID: 22
sum: -1
success
```

which is all correct: the number of rows, the ratingID of the first row and the sum.

But why doesn't it loop trough all the other rows as well? I used this at another part and it worked fine...

Thanks in advance,
Julian

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly with the above code?

Comment: Because initial `$result` is overwritten with `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Comment: Remove terminator sign from your query **;**

Comment: In addition to @u_mulder you have also another error in your code: Replace `mysqli_error` with `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bewertungen;");

while($rating = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
echo "number of rows: " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . "<br>";
$sql="
    SELECT SUM(rating_direction)
    FROM commentratings
    WHERE comment_ID = '".$rating['ID']."';
";
echo "ratingID: " . $rating['ID'] . "<br>";

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);   //result -> result2
if (FALSE === $result2) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);    //result -> result2
$sum = $row[0];
if ($row[0] == false) $sum = 0;

echo "sum: " . $sum ."<br>";

$sql="
    UPDATE bewertungen
    SET Bewertung_Kommentar = '$sum'
    WHERE ID = ".$rating['ID'].";
";

if ($con->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    echo 'success';
}
}

?>
```